# when installl hue ，PEP440Warning: 'targetcli-fb (2.1.fb46)' is being parsed as a legacy

Tags: python-2.7, hue

install hue4.1.0 on centos7 , An error occurred while implementing make apps. the error log is as follows， 
however targetcli-fb has been installed . I can't solve it, please help me to solve it

```
make[2]: Enter the directory “/root/hue-4.1.0/desktop/core”
--- Building egg for cryptography-1.3.1`enter code here`
/root/hue-4.1.0/build/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py:2510: PEP440Warning: 'targetcli-fb (2.1.fb46)' is being parsed as a legacy, non PEP 440, version. You may find odd behavior and sort order. In particular it will be sorted as less than 0.0. It is recommend to migrate to PEP 440 compatible versions.
  PEP440Warning,
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/root/hue-4.1.0/build/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 238, in run_setup
    raise
 ...
 ...
  File "/root/hue-4.1.0/build/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2316, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
ImportError: No module named setuptools_ext
make[2]: *** [/root/hue-4.1.0/desktop/core/build/cryptography-1.3.1/egg.stamp] error 1
make[2]: Leave the directory “/root/hue-4.1.0/desktop/core”
make[1]: *** [.recursive-install-bdist/core] error 2
make[1]: Leave the directory “/root/hue-4.1.0/desktop”
make: *** [install-desktop] error 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about hue, but there is the source code on github with a button 'issues' where you can stuff a keyword like 'setuptools'; led me to

https://github.com/cloudera/hue/issues/537

looks like python-dev is needed for this package